# Java locking of elements inside array

Tags: java, concurrency

I have dynamic array of hashtables

Can I use synchronized for each of them separately?
Like synchronized(array[1]) { code .. }, synchronized(array[2]) { code .. }

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This question doesn't make sense without a bit of context.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly synchronize on the object in a particular position in the array writing:

```
synchronized (arr[x]) {
  ...
}
```

However, just be careful to make sure you understand whether this is doing what you want it to do.

This will lock on the particular *object* referenced by arr[x]. However, it won't buy you any thread-safety in terms of accesses to the array itself-- in other words, for example:

- while you're locking on the object at arr[x], another thread could still potentially change which object is at arr[x];
- if two threads simultaneously access the same position of arr (either to read which hash map/object is there, or to set a new one), there'll be a race condition.

I also tend to agree with akappa -- what you're doing sounds slightly unusual, and it might be better to rephrase your question as "what data structure do I need in order to do X" rather than assuming that an array of hashmaps is the appropriate one from the outset?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but it's better to use a [concurrent map](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) os a [concurrent skip list](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) for throughput concerns, if you can.

BTW, if you provide us a bit of context, we can suggest you a (maybe) better data organization and structure.

Comment: Yea, I would argue there is absolutely no reason to use a hastable ever.